# how do i change only the eye color on an image (uiimage)?

Tags: ios, image, colors

I have an iphone app with a picture of a face in the uiimage.  I want to only change the eye color on the face by tapping on a button or tapping on a color wheel.  Can you give me some help in what code I would need.

Comment: Does the app already know the position and radius of the eye, or does it need to find this out?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at OpenCV. It works quite well on iOS devices, the main code comes with examples on how to build iOS applications and there is a lot of material on how to do [eye detection](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Eye_Detection) and from there you should be able to change the colors.

Keep in mind this is not a simple task and you could accomplish with a easier thing. But you could learn a lot and there are tons of good resources around this topics.

If you want to do something faster, you might be able to just detect the touch on the UIView(enable user interaction) and present a color picker, after the color has been presented you could create a simple view on top of the image that has a circle with the color that was selected. It would be crappy, but might be a good idea to do a simple simple prototype.